# How to check if a key in python dictionary exist in mongo db. If exist update the key value of that key in mongoDB

Tags: pymongo

I have a python dictionary that has 
RESULT= {'04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22': [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}, {'4531': '0.44331446284643317'}

key = 04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22 and [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}] are key values.

I have a document in mongoDB with same key and different key values.

collection = db["DOCUMENT"]

DOCUMENT={ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5270c4464cc8210eb5f683"), "ID" : "04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22" : [ { "7173" : "0.4076433655407347" }, { "526" : "0.3878485824518719" }]

I want to do a check, if ID in result is found in document, it has to be updated else upsert=T.

```
        for key in RESULT.keys():
        print(key)
        collection.update_one({"ID": key}, {"$set": RESULT}, upsert = True)
```

This code only inserts new data and fails to update but appends resulting in duplication.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples I'm afraid have some errors, however I suspect that you will need the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator. With a bit of tidy up, the code below works.

```
collection =db['DOCUMENT']
#                                                                                                               You are missing "])" from the end --- v
# RESULT = {'04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22': [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}, {'4531': '0.44331446284643317'}
RESULT =   {'04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22': [{'7219': '0.49954929481682875'}, {'1416': '0.48741579334133667'}, {'4531': '0.44331446284643317'}]}

#                 You have a "double colon" in your JSON which is invalid --- v                                        v                                 You are missing "})" from the end --- v
# db.document.insert_one({ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5270c4464cc8210eb5f683"), "ID" : "04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22" : [ { "7173" : "0.4076433655407347" }, { "526" : "0.3878485824518719" }]
collection.insert_one({"04BB30FC-5476-11DD-A31F-17FB9CFF4B22" : [ { "7173" : "0.4076433655407347" }, { "526" : "0.3878485824518719" }]})

print(collection.find_one({}))

for key in RESULT.keys():
    print(key)
    collection.update_one({key: {"$exists": True}}, {"$set": RESULT}, upsert = True)

print(collection.find_one({}))
```